# Fazer consultas numa view, no padrão MVC, é uma prática ruim?

Tags: mvc, design-pattern

Sei que a maioria dos frameworks em PHP é utilizado o padrão `MVC`. Onde cara coisa (teóricamente) deveria ficar em seu determinado lugar.

Por exemplo, os controllers são responsáveis pela requisição e outras coisas, os models são as abstrações da base de dados, e a view é a camada de visualização.

Porém eu já vi alguns programadores que fazem, por exemplo, consultas usando o model dentro da camada de visualização.

Um exemplo:

```
  @foreach(Estado::where($usuario->estado_id)->where('status', '=', 1)->get() as $estado)
  <div>{{ $estado->nome }}</div>
  @endforeach
```

Noto que fica bem desorganizado quando isso ocorre.

Então quero saber se, **levando em consideração o padrão MVC**, isso é uma prática ruim, ou pode ser considerado um erro da parte do programador?

Comment: É ruim.........

Comment: É mau sim.. As vezes isso acontece por exemplo a comparar variáveis com constantes e etc.. mas nesse caso que mostrou.. é claramente um erro

Comment: Levando em consideração o padrão MVC, pois sem levar essa consideração, seria baseado em opiniões.

Comment: É erro do PHP e do laravel isso, sem choro :P

Comment: Erro você fala porque ele permite deixar isso acontecer?

Comment: Já o cakephp não dá pra fazer umas lambanças dessas

Answer (score 1):

A ideia do padrão MVC é separar os conceitos, no caso do web o código que tem algum funcionalidade(controller e model) e view que geralmente é um arquivo com código de pouca ou nenhuma lógica.

Nesse exemplo, é feita uma consulta diretamente na view e está sendo feito algum tratamento? o que acontece quando ocorrer um erro? Em outras palavras um código de 'baixo nível' está sendo excutado em uma camada de um nível mais alto. A solução para isso é fazer a consulta no controller e a partir dele despachar a lista de estados para a view.

Comment: Mas é um erro ou não é?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é violada a ideia principal do padrão e se não tiver um bom motivo para isso, é uma indicação de que tem algo errado.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se achar q precisa de mais alguma coisa avisa ai, que edito depois a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração o padrão MVC é um erro do programador, apesar de muitos frameworks permitirem essa prática funcionar. Mas nem tudo que funciona segue um padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Costumo comparar estes casos com alguém que conduz um veículo sem ter habilitação. Existe uma norma que define como e quem pode dirigir, tanto quanto existe um padrão arquitetural que define como e quem devem ter cada responsábilidade em uma aplicação, neste caso o MVC.

Não respeitar as definições do padrão é tão errado quanto dirigir sem carteira de habilitação.

Fato é que este código, á principio, funciona, bem como existem pessoas não habilitadas dirigindo melhor do que habilitados, mas partindo de uma definição prévia de padrões e responsábilidade, sim, este código está errado e quem conduz sem habilitação também.

Outro detalhe que acho importante é que, no caso dos padrões arquiteturais, não há uma lei que te obrigue a usá-los, logo, quando assumi-se a disposição de não aplicar o padrão este mesmo código já não está mais errado.

Usar ou não usar o padrão? Eis a questão!

Certa vez participei de um projeto para reescrever uma aplicação visto que refatorá-la custaria mais caro. As páginas (centenas) eram cheias deste tipo de código, os controladores escreviam html hard code no response, enfim, era "impossível" saber quem fazia o que, de tal forma que uma mudança visual (escopo inicial do projeto) se tornou mais caro do que refazê-lo. Particularmente eu diria SEMPRE use (e de forma correta) um padrão (MVC ou outro que seja aderente).