# Como seria o `Padrão MVC` nesse caso?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Como seria o `Padrão MVC` nesse caso?

Bom, tenho uma classe `Tipos`, uma classe `TiposDao` e um `formulário` php para cadastrar um tipo.

Essa Classe `Tipos`    seria a `Model`.
Essa Classe `TiposDao` seria a `Controller`.

Mas, como ficaria a `View` dessa Classe?

Seria o proprio formulário?

Ou seria o arquivo php que lista os tipos disponíveis?

Segue as classes:

Classe Tipos:

```
<?php
 class Tipos{

     private $idTipos;
     private $nome;

     public function __construct($_nome)
     {
         $this->nome = $_nome;
     }

     public function setidTipos($_idTipos) {
         $this->idTipos = $_idTipos;
     }

     public function getidTipos () {
         return $this->idTipos;
     }

     public function getNome () {
         return $this->nome;
     }

}
?>
```

Classe TiposDao:

```
<?php 
 class TiposDao {

     private $conexao;

     public function __construct ($_conexao) {      
         $this->conexao = $_conexao;
     }

     public function excluir ($idTipo) {         

         $string = "DELETE FROM tipos WHERE idTipos = ".$idTipo;
         $this->conexao->query($string);

     }

     public function cadastrar ($tipo) {         

         $string = "INSERT INTO tipos (nome) VALUES ('".$tipo->getNome()."')";
         $this->conexao->query($string);

     }

     public function ultimoIdCadastrado () {         
         return $this->conexao->insert_id;
     }

     public function editar ($tipo) {        

         $string = "UPDATE tipos 
                    SET 
                      nome = '".$tipo->getNome()."'
                    WHERE 
                      idTipos = ".$tipo->getidTipos();
        $this->conexao->query($string);
     }


     public function pesquisaTipoNome($nome) {
         $tipo = null;           

         $string = "SELECT idTipos, nome
                    FROM tipos 
                    WHERE nome= '".$nome."'";

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {
             list ($idTipos, $nome) = $registros->fetch_row();
             $tipo = new tipos($nome);                       
             $tipo->setidTipos($idTipos);
         }

         return $tipo;

     }

     public function pesquisaTipoId($idTipo) {
         $tipo = null;           

         $string = "SELECT idTipos, nome 
                    FROM tipos 
                    WHERE idTipos = ".$idTipo;

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {

             list ($idTipos, $nome) = $registros->fetch_row();
             $tipo = new Tipos($nome);                       
             $tipo->setidTipos($idTipos);
         }

         return $tipo;

     }

     public function pesquisaNomeTipo($idTipo) {
         $tipo = null;           

         $string = "SELECT nome 
                    FROM tipos 
                    WHERE idTipos = ".$idTipo;

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {

             list ($nome) = $registros->fetch_row();
             $tipo = $nome;
         }

         return $tipo;

     }

     public function pesquisaTipos() {
         $tipos = null;           

         $string = "SELECT idTipos, nome FROM tipos";

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows; 

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0) {

             while (list ($idTipos, $nome) = $registros->fetch_row()) {

                 $tipo = new Tipos($nome);                       
                 $tipo->setidTipos($idTipos);

                 $tipos[] = $tipo;
             }
         }

         return $tipos;

     }
 }
?>
```

Arquivo cadastraTipos.php

```
<?php

 require_once "../_controlls/_daos/AdminsDao.php";
 require_once "../_controlls/_models/Tipos.php";
 require_once "../_controlls/_daos/TiposDao.php";



$AdminsDao = new AdminsDao($conexao);
$TiposDao = new TiposDao($conexao);

if(isset($_GET["acao"]) && $_GET["acao"] == "form") {
?>
  <h1 class="h1Centralizado">Cadastrar Tipo</h1>
<div style="width:500px">  
  <form action="?" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cadastrar" /> <br />
    <label class="labelPequeno">Nome</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="200" id="nome" name="nome" required /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar Tipo" /><br /> <br />
  </form>
</div>
<?php   
}

if (isset($_POST["acao"]) && $_POST["acao"] == "cadastrar") {

      $nome = $_POST["nome"];

    if( $nome == "" ) {
        echo "<h1 class='h1CentralizadoAvisos'>Algum campo ficou sem preecher!</h1>";     
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<div style='text-align:center'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'><img src='_img/voltar.png' title='Voltar' /></a><br /><br />";  
    }
    else
    {       
            $tipo = new Tipos($nome);                   
            $TiposDao->cadastrar($tipo);

                echo "<h1 class='h1Centralizado'>Cadastro feito com sucesso!</h1>";       
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<div style='text-align:center'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'><img src='_img/voltar.png' title='Voltar' /></a><br /><br />";  

              $connection->fechaConexao();
    }   

}
?>
```

Comment: Se "tiposDAO" segue o padrão DAO, e serve para realizar operações no banco, na tabela tipos, acredito que também faz parte do model. Controller seria a classe que utiliza tipoDAO, para obter acesso a objetos do tipo "Tipo". A view só vai receber parâmetros do Controller, e com base nisso, renderizar a tela (HTML) que será exibida pra o usuário.

Comment: É realmente necessário fazer isso ai no braço? recomendo que utilize um framework, tipo Laravel ou Cakephp, se for possível.

Comment: Sua view está fazendo mais coisas do que deveria, mais sobre isso [veja aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118294/91)

Comment: [Como e para que usar MVC no PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114824/91)

Comment: Minha View seria o arquivo cadastraTipos;php?

Comment: Sim, serie esse arquivo mesmo,mas a ideia do MVC é que a view só recebe os valores, em seguida, encaminha para o controler, que por sua vez, passa os dados para o model (ou DAO) para persistir no banco. Acredito que criar uma estrutura MVC, sem nem conhecer direito o padrão, é uma péssima ideia, tenta usar algum framework, veja como as coisas funcionam nele.

Comment: Só uma dica: MVC e PHP não funcionam bem juntos. A framework ideal para "forçar" o programador a usar MVC é JSF. Recomendo que você dê uma olhada já que está pensando em seguir uma arquitetura MVC.